# How to change ONLY color of selection text and save default background color (css)

Tags: html, css, text, selection

Each OS has its own text selection settings. It can be changed by `::selection` pseudo-class, but when I set attribute `color`, attribute `background` becomes transparent automatically. How to avoid this?

Comment: example https://codepen.io/KATERINA198BB/pen/mdbQKgE

Answer (score 0):

Use this below css to change the background.

```
.lol {
  color: green;
}
.lol::selection {
  color: red;
  background:#3297fd;
}
```

Comment: I don't want change background, ONLY color